# Read delimited multiline string file into multiple arrays in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, indexing

I began with a file like so:

```
Table_name1 - Table_desc1
Table_name2 - Table_desc2
...
...
```

I have a script that parses this file and splits them into two arrays:

```
declare -a TABLE_IDS=()
declare -a TABLE_DESCS=()

while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "${line}" ]]; do
  TABLE_IDS[i]=${line%' '-' '*}
  TABLE_DESCS[i++]=${line#*' '-' '}
done < "${TABLE_LIST}"

for i in "${!TABLE_IDS[@]}"; do
        echo "Creating Table ID: "${TABLE_IDS[i]}", with Table Description: "${TABLE_DESCS[i]}""
done
```

This works really well, with no problems whatsoever.

I wanted to extend this and make the file:

```
Table_name1 - Table_desc1 - Table_schema1
Table_name2 - Table_desc2 - Table_schema2
...
...
```

For this, I tried:

```
declare -a TABLE_IDS=()
declare -a TABLE_DESCS=()

while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "${line}" ]]; do
  TABLE_IDS[i]="$(echo $line | cut -f1 -d - | tr -d ' ')"
  TABLE_DESCS[i++]="$(echo $line | cut -f2 -d - | tr -d ' ')"
  TABLE_SCHEMAS[i++]="$(echo $line | cut -f3 -d - | tr -d ' ')"
done < "${TABLE_LIST}"

for i in "${!TABLE_IDS[@]}"; do
        echo "Creating Table ID: "${TABLE_IDS[i]}", with Table Description: "${TABLE_DESCS[i]}" and schema: "${TABLE_SCHEMAS[i]}""
done
```

And while this will faithfully list all the Table IDs and the Table descriptions, the schemas are omitted. I tried:

```
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "${line}" ]]; do
  TABLE_IDS[i]="$(echo $line | cut -f1 -d - | tr -d ' ')"
  TABLE_DESCS[i]="$(echo $line | cut -f2 -d - | tr -d ' ')"
  TABLE_SCHEMAS[i]="$(echo $line | cut -f3 -d - | tr -d ' ')"
done < "${TABLE_LIST}"
```

And it returns just the last line's Table name, description AND schema. I suspect this is an indexing/looping problem, but am unable to figure out what exactly is going wrong. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Are the names, descriptions and schemas always strings without whitespace?

Comment: You have `i++` twice in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps set the delimiter to the actual delimiter `-` and do the processing in the read loop instead of deferring and using arrays.

```
$ while IFS=- read -r t d s; 
  do 
    echo "Creating Table ID: ${t// }, with Table Description: ${d// } and schema: ${s// }";
  done < file
```

Comment: Works perfectly! As @Benjamin W. asked above, I do have spaces in my table description. If you could try and modify the answer to retain the spaces between the words of the description, while stripping leading and trailing spaces, it would be the nothing short of awesome! I am looking for solutions to that though, so...

Comment: Ended up using `$( echo $d | xargs )` for the description. Works fine, and is minimally invasive.

Comment: I removed white space with `${t// }` just to remove the trailing space change to `{t%%+( )}`

Comment: I'd need to remove both leading and trailing spaces. This was the easier way to do it :)